# How can I extract the last X folders from the path in k shell

Tags: shell, sed, ksh, csh

Say I have a path name `/server/user/folderA/folderB/folderC`, how would I extract (to a variable) just the last few folders? I'm looking for something that will be flexible enough to give me `folderC`, or `folderB/folderC`, or `folderA/folderB/folderC`, etc.

I'm trying to use sed, but I'm not sure that's the best approach.

This would have to be in either ksh or csh (no bash on our machines, sadly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with perl if you've got it:

```
$ path=/server/user/folderA/folderB/folderC
$ X=3
$ echo $path|perl -F/ -ane '{print join "/",@F[(@F-'$X')..(@F-1)]}'
folderA/folderB/folderC
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I would also like to find a non-perl solution (as I'm never 100% what will be available), but this will do the job perfectly in 3 lines.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started:

```
arr=( $(echo "/server/user/folderA/folderB/folderC" | sed 's#/# #g') )

echo ${#arr[*]}
echo ${arr[*]}
echo ${arr[3]}
echo "${arr[2]}/${arr[3]}/${arr[4]}"
```

**output**

```
 5
 server user folderA folderB folderC
 folderB
 folderA/folderB/folderC
```

IHTH

Comment: I'm getting an error on ksh about the parenthesis  

`/Test.ksh[3]: syntax error at line 5 : (' unexpected`

Comment: Where line 5 is your initial `arr=( $(echo "/server/user/folderA/folderB/folderC" | sed 's#/# #g') )` line

Comment: It works perfectly on my other machine which runs bash, but the machine I need this on only supports csh and ksh

Comment: I can see that the sed line is replacing the '/'s with spaces, now the question is just how to break a string that contains spaces into an array.

Comment: my code was written and tested in a ksh environment. Does `echo ${sh.version}` return a value or an error? Your original Q didn't specify spaces in the path :-/

Comment: `echo ${sh.version}` gives me  
`Variable syntax.`

Comment: There aren't spaces in the path, it just seemed to me that your solution was creating them with sed, then using the `( $(....))` syntax to break the string apart at the spaces into an array. I may have interpreted that incorrectly.

Comment: You're `/bin/ksh` is a ksh 88 version. Look for `ksh93` in your system, or if on Sun, `/usr/xpg4/bin/ksh*`. I'm not sure what your comment/question about "a string that contains spaces" refers to. If that is an issue, post a new Q with sample input and required output from same input. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays, but ksh88 (at least the one I tested with, on Solaris 8) uses the old Korn Shell syntax of `set -A`, and it doesn’t do `(( i++ ))` either, so this looks a bit more baroque than contemporary ksh93 or mksh code. On the other hand, I’m also giving you a function to extract the last *n* items ;)

```
p=/server/user/folderA/folderB/folderC
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=/
set -A fullpath -- $p
echo all: "${fullpath[*]}"
unset fullpath[0] # leading slash
unset fullpath[1]
unset fullpath[2]
echo all but first two: "${fullpath[*]}"
IFS=$saveIFS

# example function to get the last n:
function pathlast {
        typeset saveIFS parr i=0 n

        saveIFS=$IFS
        IFS=/
        set -A parr -- $2
        (( n = ${#parr[*]} - $1 ))
        while (( i < n )); do
                unset parr[i]
                (( i += 1 ))
        done
        echo "${parr[*]}"
        IFS=$saveIFS
}

for lst in 1 2 3; do
        echo all but last $lst: $(pathlast $lst "$p")
done
```

Output:

```
tg@stinky:~ $ /bin/ksh x
all: /server/user/folderA/folderB/folderC
all but first two: folderA/folderB/folderC
all but last 1: folderC
all but last 2: folderB/folderC
all but last 3: folderA/folderB/folderC
```

Other than the first line setting `$p`, you can just copy the function part.